# Help restoring old wood beam please!

Tags: wood, beam, old-house, paint-removal, drywall-mud

I am in the process of trying to uncover an original beam in my 120 year old home. The beam appears to have been painted (possibly twice), then covered in drywall mud, then painted again. It's tested negative for lead, so no need to express concern for that! I had tried paint remover but with the layer of drywall mud, it creates more of a mess than its worth. My most successful technique so far has been sanding it all off, but obviously this is extremely time consuming and creates a dust storm. Any better suggestions on how to get down to the wood? I'm eager to get to the next step in this project.

Thanks,
Britt

Comment: First, did you check all the levels of paint for lead, not just the surface?

Comment: Will the sheetrock mud chip off? That might be faster but I don't know.

Comment: The curse of the DIYer... "eager to get to the next step".  Take your time and do the existing step correctly.

Comment: Could remove as much of the mud as possible and then hit it with an electric planer to get down to the wood. Messy and potentially dangerous if there's lead in the paint.

Comment: You should have the mud tested for asbestos.

Comment: @gnicko  Would also worry about hidden nails/screws under the mud using power planer.  Quite sure after 120 years someone knocked a nail or two in.  Don't think electric planners like nails that much.

Comment: @crip659 Very true.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed some awful stuff with a paint scraper - specifically, a sharp tungsten carbide paint scraper (they stay sharp enough to use (much) longer than steel and the blades are reversible for 2 sharp edges per blade.) They make shavings more than dust, though the drywall mud will likely go to dust or paint-clumped chunks.

If sanding, a shop vac with a good filter connected to the sander is well worth the expense on any sizable job (and then you have it for any sized job, unless you rent it because you don't see a future use for it.)